# change listview's button visibility in an activity

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter, visibility

I have a `ListView` which has a button inside its each rows, I declare the `Button` inside my `ListView` adapter, this `Button` is invisible but I need to change the `Button` view to visible for some cases.
as the `Button` declare in `Listview` adapter class, I am not able to access to it to change its visibility.
any idea to how i can manage it?

this is my `Adapter`:

```
    public class MessageSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
public String mId;
private static List<HashMap<String, String>> listMapBGMessage;
private static Context context;
private static int resource;
private GroupMadeByUserActivity _recAct;

protected static int[] resourceList;
protected static String[] fromList;


private static class ViewHolder {

    TextView[] tv_bid_group_name;
    ImageView iv_bid_group_delete;
    TextView[] tv_bid_group_comment;

    int position;
}

public MessageSimpleAdapter(Context context,
        List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from,
        int[] to, GroupMadeByUserActivity recAct) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    // save the ArrayList and context for later usage
    MessageSimpleAdapter.listMapBGMessage = data;
    MessageSimpleAdapter.context = context;
    MessageSimpleAdapter.resource = resource;

    _recAct = recAct;
    resourceList = to;
    fromList = from;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // declare it final so that it could be accessed from the inner class
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MessageSimpleAdapter.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(MessageSimpleAdapter.resource,
                parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_bid_group_name = new TextView[fromList.length];
        holder.tv_bid_group_comment = new TextView[fromList.length];

        // get the textview's from the convertView
        for (int i = 0; i < fromList.length; i++) {
            holder.tv_bid_group_name[i] = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(resourceList[i]);
            holder.tv_bid_group_comment[i] = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(resourceList[i]);

        }

        // get the phoneIcon and emailIcon as well from convertView
        holder.iv_bid_group_delete = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_bid_group_delete);



        // add a listener for phone call
        holder.iv_bid_group_delete
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        GroupMadeByUserActivity.messageIdStatic = MessageSimpleAdapter.listMapBGMessage
                                .get(holder.position).get("IDMessage");

                        _recAct.new AsyncDeleteMessage().execute(GroupMadeByUserActivity.messageIdStatic);

                    }

                });

        // store it in a Tag as its the first time this view is generated
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        /* get the View from the existing Tag */
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    /* update the textView's text for this list view item/element */
    for (int i = 0; i < fromList.length; i++) {
        holder.tv_bid_group_name[i].setText(listMapBGMessage.get(position)
                .get(fromList[i]));
    }

    // store the position/index for this list view element/item
    holder.position = position;

    return convertView;
}

    }
```

Comment: Which is the `Button` you are talking about and what do you mean, " I am not able to access"? How did you try to access it and how did it fail?

Comment: You can only change the Visibility in the getView method of you adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the visibility in your adapter `getView`. Check the condition and change the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see another way than changing it in your adapter. 
Does your adapter know the reasons for the decision? If not, you could pass them at creation.

If you want to outsource the decision itself you could do it like that in your `getView`:

```
...
boolean isVisible = MyUtil.isButtonVisible(listMapBGMessage.get(position)); // pass the object or an id
int visibility = isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE; // GONE or INVISIBLE
holder.iv_bid_group_delete.setVisibility(visibility);
```

This way you can centralize the desicion in your `public static boolean isButtonVisible(...)` and the adapter doesn't need to know the reasons but just gets the decision.

Answer (score 0):

a filed like :

```
public View getView(...) {
        ...
        holder.myBUTON.setVisibility(buttonsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE)
        ...
    }
```

> boolean isVisible =
>   MyUtil.isButtonVisible(listMapBGMessage.get(position)); // pass the
>   object or an id int visibility = isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
>   // GONE or INVISIBLE
>   holder.iv_bid_group_delete.setVisibility(visibility);

After :

> notifyDataSetChanged();

or you can create a method where you set Visible or Invisible button and after notifiy for see the changes.